# How to call major or minor on dev_t using Swift

Tags: swift, darwin

I obtained a value of type `dev_t` and I would like to access to the major and minor versions number of it, unfortunately while in C you would call `major(theValue)` or `minor(theValue)` they aren't defined in Swift (probably because they are just macros ?).

How should I do this ?

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`dev_t` is an signed 32-bit integer. `major` returns the most significant 8-bits and `minor` returns the least significant 24-bits.

```
let x: dev_t = 0x12345678

func major(_ x: dev_t) -> Int32 {
    return (x >> 24) & 0xff
}

func minor(_ x: dev_t) -> Int32 {
    return x & 0xffffff
}

print(String(major(x), radix: 16))
print(String(minor(x), radix: 16))
```

Output:

> 12
>   345678

Comment: Minor remark: `dev_t` alias `__darwin_dev_t` is a *signed* 32-bit integer, at least on macOS.

Comment: @ rmaddy @MartinR Is this a UInt64 on Linux ?

Comment: @TrevörAnneDenise: On Ubuntu `dev_t` is an `unsigned long int` ( `UInt` in Swift). major/minor are implemented as gnu_dev_major/minor library functions, but also available as macros, e.g. `return ((__dev >> 8) & 0xfff) | ((unsigned int) (__dev >> 32) & ~0xfff);` for the device major number.

Comment: @TrevörAnneDenise: On Linux you can simply call `gnu_dev_major(UInt64(x))` to get the major device number

Answer (score 3):

Yes, the problem is that `major/minor` are defined as nontrivial macros in `<sys/types.h>`:

```
#define major(x)        ((int32_t)(((u_int32_t)(x) >> 24) & 0xff))
#define minor(x)        ((int32_t)((x) & 0xffffff))
```

and therefore not available in Swift.

A possible solution is to define  helper functions
in the bridging header file (where the macros *are* available):

```
#include <sys/types.h>

static inline int32_t dev_major(dev_t x) { return major(x); }
static inline int32_t dev_minor(dev_t x) { return minor(x); }
```

These can then be used from Swift:

```
func foo(device: dev_t) {
    let ma = dev_major(device)
    let mi = dev_minor(device)
}
```

---

On Linux you can call the corresponding library functions in Glibc:

```
func foo(device: dev_t) {
    let ma = gnu_dev_major(UInt64(device))
    let mi = gnu_dev_minor(UInt64(device))
}
```

Comment: Gosh, I really hate the use of macros for things that `const`s and functions can do

Comment: @Alexander: You'll find a lot of that in the system headers :) – I tried to find a solution that you can *use* the existing system definition.

Comment: I'm aware, but I never really understood why. It *does* guarantee inlining, I guess, but does that really matter with modern optimizer? Is there some benefit I'm missing?

Comment: What's the issue with doing that?

Comment: @Alexander: I'm not sure If I understood you correctly.  Is your comment about macros in the system header files, or about "static inline" in my proposed solution?

Comment: You had said that macros are the only way to define functions in headers, but said that as an alternative, you could declare the function in the header but implement them in a C file. I'm curious why that isn't done. What's the issue of just having one more C file?

Comment: @Alexander: None really. I just found it simpler to add 2 lines to the bridging header file (which you might have anyway). Of course you can define helper functions in a C file, the declarations in a H file and include the H file from the bridging header. – My main point is that you use the existing definitions instead of replicating them.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/163447/discussion-between-alexander-and-martin-r).